# Sometimes the console doesn't have any output

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Sometimes while the app is running in simulator(I started it from Xcode and they were linked), If I re-run the app (still in stimulator) then sometimes the console shows absolutely nothing. The only thin I can do is kill the stimulator and restart it.

Hint: every time If the console shows nothing, the breaking points I set in AppDelegate (in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method) would never be triggered.

I think maybe the Xcode sometimes skips part of the compile-link job to accelerate app booting, and somehow the LLDB debugger would be ignored thus console would show nothing. It's just my guess though, I dont know what exactly happened and how should I avoid it.

Comment: So, what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to print out? You can NSLog different statements or use po objectNameHere when you hit a breakpoint.

If it isn't hitting breakpoints then you don't have them enabled or the code doesn't go into those methods.